# Maintain two priority queues of objects of the same type, with different sort attributes for each

Tags: python, class, sorting, binary-search, priority-queue

So, I have a class `P`. I want to two priority queues of objects of type `P`, as well as a priority queue of objects of type `P`. However, I want to order one of them on `P.x`, and order the other on `P.y`. Now, `queue.PriorityQueue.put()` does not support a key function, so I resorted to doing the following:

```
class P:
    ...
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.y < other.y
    ...
```

However, this does not allow for sorting based on `P.x`, and at the same time, I want to peek one of the queues but not the other, and `queue.PriorityQueue` does not have a `peek` function. Therefore, I replaced one of the priority queues with a sorted list instead. I can't use the `SortedContainers` library, because this is for a homework assignment and I can't guarantee that the grading server has it installed, so I turned to using `bisect.insort`.

The only problem, however, is that `bisect.insort` also does not support key functions. Therefore, I had to write my own function `binary_insert(lst, item, key)` to accomplish this task, and then I call it with `binary_insert(lst, item, key = lambda i: i.x)`. This feels like a hack, since I'm writing my own binary insertion function, and binary insertion is such a core computer science concept that this must have come up before.

One way to do it would be to have the list store tuples of the form `(x, p)`, and have the priority queue store tuples of the form `(y, p)`. But, is there any other way to internalize these attributes into `P` itself? Otherwise, I will have to unpack a tuple every time I pop off an item, and this may cause my program to become littered with unused variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can subclass `PriorityQueue` to do the tuples for you, something like this (totally untested code):

```py
class MyPriorityQueue(PriorityQueue):
    def _put(self, item):
        super()._put((item.x, item))

    def _get(self):
        return super()._get()[1]
```